# Changing the color of ActionBar area to green

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am new to Android `ActionBar`. Currently I am trying to create a menu in an `ActionBar` area but it always comes in black color. Can any one help me in changing the background color of the `ActionBar`, please?
Here I am attaching my works please have a look,

themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ThemeUtil.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

color.xml

```
    <color name="actionbar_background">#008080</color>
```

manifest.xml

```
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, you should use `AppCompatActivity`.

If `CustomActionBarTheme` is set as `android:theme` in your manifest file, then there is no need to use `ThemeUtil`. Remove it from your `MainActivity`. Then, re-write your `styles.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">/*This will tint the status bar on lollipop devices*/</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

So long as your style extends `Theme.AppCompat.*`, then `colorPrimary` sets the ActionBar colour automatically. On Lolllipop devices, `colorPrimaryDark` sets the status bar colour. `accent` sets the colour for some widget items.

Comment: Can you please give me some example how it will work for Lolllipop devices @PPartisan

Comment: @PraneshSahu Sure. Simply add an `<item name="colorPrimaryDark"></item>` element to your style. On Lollipop devices, this will tint the status bar, but have no effect oon pre-lollipop devices. I'll add it to my answer.